# Как выполнять определённый код раз в минуту

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно чтобы код выполнялся раз в минуту, но это не получается.. Я придумал такой код но он не работает раз в минуту, а выполняется просто как обычный while очень быстро.

```
while True:
    print('f')
    asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Comment: `import time` `time.sleep(60)`

Comment: А как ты придумал такой код? На основе чего?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Набросаю несколько вариантов

1. Использование `time.sleep`

```
from time import sleep

while True:
   # do something
   sleep(60)
```

2. Использование библиотеки `schedule`

```
# pip install schedule

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().minute.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

3. Использовать `celery`. Для этого способа нужно дополнительно установить `rabbitmq` либо `redis`.

```
# tasks.py
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('tasks', broker='адрес брокера')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add': {
        'task': 'add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    }
}
```

Запускаем это командами `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO` и `celery -A tasks beat --loglevel=INFO`

Answer (score 3):

Вы забыли добавить `await` перед использованием асинхронной функции:

```py
while True:
    print('f')
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```